# How to enable Always-On VPN in Android programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm using open VPN base on https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn
and the default always-on VPN is disabled.

How can it be enabled programmatically in android?

[here is what i expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j91Gt.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

You have to declare the `SERVICE_META_DATA_SUPPORTS_ALWAYS_ON` metadata for your VPN service. For details, read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService#service_meta_data_supports_always_on .

Comment: did you successfully manage to switch it on?